# how to get the exact year from the given date in oracle if it has a minimal format to base from?

Tags: sql, oracle

how to get the exact "year" from oracle data if the given data is in this format?

```
02-FEB-84
```

I want to get the year, but when I do something like this

```
  case
   when dob is not null then to_date(dob,'YYYY')
   when dob is null then '""'
  end
as yearofbirth
```

I am getting the value of

```
2084
```

when I was expecting

```
1984
```

how to solve this?, because my query is not smart enough to determine if the year is from the 19th century or 20th century

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `DOB` is `varchar2()` having date in format `DD-MON-YY`,
You might be looking for

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DOB,'DD-MON-RR'),'YYYY')
```

Conversion using `YY` format! Current century is 20** so, 84 -> 2084

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02-FEB-84','DD-MON-YY'),'YYYY') FROM DUAL;

TO_C
----
2084
```

Conversion using `RR` format! Current century is 20** and year is < 2050 so, 84 -> 1984

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02-FEB-84','DD-MON-RR'),'YYYY') FROM DUAL;

TO_C
----
1984
```

Comment: daemn, you nailed it. thank you Sir, and to everyone who tried to help me fix my problem

Comment: What changes needs to made to make it work on SQL Server? I've tried SELECT CONVERT(date,'16/06/66','DD/MM/RRRR'), but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

One more condition to your case statement should do it.

```
case
when to_date(dob) > sysdate then to_date(dob,'YYYY') - 100
when dob is not null then to_date(dob,'YYYY')
when dob is null then '""'
end
as yearofbirth
```

Comment: I got this error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

Comment: @Dan, why are you imposing to_date on a date column? To display a date you need to use to_char with proper format mask.

Answer (score 1):

You just hit the Y2K bug. You need to use the 'RR' format to get the proper YEAR result in 2 digits.

**If you have used 'RR' format than it understands it as 1984 and if you have use 'YY' format it understands as 2084.
In general A value between 0-49 will return a 20xx year.
A value between 50-99 will return a 19xx year.**

```
select to_date('84','RR') from dual
```

Always, remember, an year must be YYYY(4 digits) and not YY. The world has already spent too much time fixing the Y2K bug.

You can read more about 'RR' format here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00215

**Update : You need to use to_char if you want to display the year using 'RR' format.**

```
Select to_char(dob,'RR') from table
```

I assume your dob column is DATE data type. A date must always be DATE data type and NOT string. Else, you need to first convert the literal into date and use to_char over it with 'RR' format.

Comment: I got this error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

Comment: Show what you did. Using to_date, you need to pass the date literal in single quotes, using to_char, you need to pass the actual date.

You might need to do to_char(dob,'RR')

Comment: I did the exact thing you suggested, and i got that error

Comment: I am still getting the exact error with either to_char OR to_date, any ideas why?

Comment: What is the DATA TYPE of your dob column? A date should always be a DATE data type, if you are using character type, probably that is why you are using to_date to convert it into date, but then you still need to use to_Char with 'RR' format.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky, for example:

```
TO_DATE('16/06/66','DD/MM/RRRR')

16/06/1966

TO_DATE('16/06/16','DD/MM/RRRR')

16/06/2016

TO_DATE('16/06/16','DD/MM/RRRR')

16/06/1916
```

For the `RRRR` mask a value between 0-49 will return a 20xx year. A value between 50-99 will return a 19xx year.

Answer (score 0):

`TO_CHAR(YOUR_TABLE_DATA_COLUMN,'YYYY')`

Comment: Could you add some explanations to your answer?